# Difference between structural type and type returned from contexpr function

Tags: c++, non-type-template-parameter

I was playing with C++ and got confused by this:

cppreference.com [says that](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/template_parameters) a non-type template parameter must be a *structural type* and that a *literal class type* is an example of a structural type. Then it [says that](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/named_req/LiteralType) “Literal types are the types of constexpr variables and they can be constructed, manipulated, and *returned from constexpr functions*” (emphasis mine). ([In fact](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/constexpr) the return type of a constexpr function *must* be a literal type.)

So my understanding was **can be returned from constexpr function** implies **is a literal type** implies **is a structural type** implies **can be used as a non-type template parameter.**

But it appears that `std::optional` *can* be returned from a constexpr function (`bar` below) but *cannot* be used as a non-type template parameter (`foo` immediately below). What's going on?

```
#include <optional>
template <std::optional<int> Z> int foo(int x) { return x; }
int main() { return foo<std::optional{0}>(0); }
```

This gives the compiler errors (GCC and clang resp.)

> <source>:2:30: error: 'std::optional' is not a valid type for a
> template non-type parameter because it is not structural

> <source>:2:30: error: type 'std::optional' of non-type template parameter
> is not a structural type

But

```
#include <optional>
constexpr std::optional<int> bar() { return std::optional{0}; }
int main() { return *bar(); }
```

compiles.

Comment: No, "literal types can be returned from constexpr functions" doesn't imply that a type being returnable from a constexpr function is literal.

Comment: @cigien Yes, that particular quote doesn't use the most precise language, but it is spelled out [here](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/constexpr) that a constexpr function's "return type (if any) must be a" literal type.

Comment: The cppreference link says "a structural type, which is ... a literal class type *with the following properties*: ...". Does `std::optional` satisfy those properties?

Comment: @cigien Oh, yeah, that's the issue. Just needed to read more. Thank you! Seems like the structural type-ness of std::optional depends on its implementation details?

Comment: @nebuch: "*that a literal class type is an example of a structural type*" No, it doesn't. It says that *some* literal types can be structural, but it also lists several requirements that the literal type must have.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

C++20 allows classes as non-type template parameters [if they are](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/template_parameters):

> a literal class type with the following properties:
>
> - all base classes and non-static data members are public and non-mutable and
> - the types of all base classes and non-static data members are structural types or (possibly multi-dimensional) array thereof.

`std::optional` is a literal class type, but it has non-public data members, so is not allowed as a non-type template parameter.

You could make your own `optional`-like class with only public data members, then it would be usable as a template parameter.